# Update a database record simultaneously with different values by different users

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, hibernate

I have designed a Web based project.

I am using Mysql database. I will perform all persistence logic in java using hibernate. All the client side actions will be done in javascript.

Here my problem is,

If two users are trying to update same record simultaneously at different places.

Initially User-1 updates by giving full information related to a single object and called save information method.

At the other end User-2 updates same record by giving partial information and called save information method.

If User-1 information is saved first User-2 information will overwrite first given information. Hence some information might loss which user-1 given but he doesn't know some thing is loosed.

Please give some suggestions to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use the Optimistic Lock. Basically this technique is to have a field in the table to tell Hibernate which your version and thus whether an object with smaller version try to overwrite the data in a larger version hibernate will throw an exception. This versioning field is usually a numeric field that hibernate increases with every update or date field. The flow is something like:

1 - The record is inserted into the base. At this point the "version" field is set to zero.

2 - The X user query the record with version 0.

3 - The Y user query the record with version 0.

4 - The Y user updates the registry information. At that moment the hibernate automatically increments the version of record for 1.

5 - The X user updates the information on the version 0 and try to save. At that moment the hibernate finds that the record is already in version 1 that is greater than the version that the user X is using, in that it throws an exception stating the problem and not allowing overwriting the most current information.

To implement this strategy simply create a numeric field in your table and then apply @Version:

```
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to consider, is a [locking](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking) strategy for your data. Using Hibernate, by default you have no locking (a.k.a. Ostrich locking or "last save wins"). Roughly, the other two options are optimistic locking and pessimistic locking.

Optimistic locking means that you do not prevent users editing data concurrently, but you will inform a user if his edit failed because the data was saved from elsewhere after it was loaded from the DB.

Pessimistic locking means that you prevent multiple users for editing the data concurrently. This is a bit more complicated form of locking and is usually neither practical nor required.

More info on implementing a locking strategy can be found from [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html). Which strategy you should choose depends a lot on your application and whether many users are expected to frequently edit the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Before user 2 updates the DB, you can check if the information in the DB (e.g. the row) is the same as it was when user 2 reached the update/edit page. e.g. you could do a SELECT on the row when the user reaches the page and again after the user has made the changes (i.e. before the row is updated) and compare these before you update the DB.

If the row is the same, there was no changes. If the row is different, someone else had edited it.